# fragment view find view by id of main view

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a `MainActivity` with an fragment view.
In the `MainActivity`, I load this layout:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.MainLayout);
}
```

In the MainLayout, is an Float Action Button with the id "fab"

In my fragment view class, I load the fragment view layout like this:

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       FragementView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.FragmentViewLayout, container, false);
       FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) FragementView .findViewById(R.id.fab);

       return FragementView;
    }
```

Now I would like to get in the fragment view class, the fab (find by id)
but this will be a null object.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: FragementView is a View?

Comment: yes, this is a View

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to get the view of activity in fragment use `getActivity()`.

Quoting docs

Specifically, the fragment can access the Activity instance with getActivity() and easily perform tasks such as find a view in the activity layout:

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fab);
```

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Answer (score 0):

Your `FloatActionButton` is in `MainLayout` layout not `FragmentViewLayout` layout.
Therefore, you should retrieve it in your `Activity` like

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.MainLayout);
  ...
  FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Include `FloatingActionButton` in your `FragmentViewLayout`

**FragmentViewLayout.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout 
...

//include FloatingActionButton here
...
/>
```